# cordova proccess hebrew fonts as gibberish

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

After digging it today seems that something with cordova build is wrong.

cordova processed the files and make all the hebrew fonts gibberish.

the files in the "output" www dir are hebrew cruppeted

[image]

Comment: Hebrew fonts should just work if the HTML page is UTF-8 encoded. How are you getting the values in this list? Place `<meta charset="utf-8">` after your `<head>` tag if you already haven't.

Comment: After digging it today seems that something with cordova build is wrong.
cordova processed the files and make all the hebrew fonts gibberish
the files in the "output" www dir are hebrew cruppeted. tag <meta charset="utf-8"> set correctly

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. seem that original cordova template files encoding was wrong.
**converting files encoding to utf-8 (using notepad++) solved the problem**

[image]